# Consider the ordinary differential equation, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4+y^2}{1+x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ordinary differential equation, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4+y^2}{1+x^2}$

If $y(1)=2$, then find the value of $y(2)$

$\int \frac{dy}{4+y^2}=\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2} -- (|)$

$\frac{1}{2}\ tan^{-1}\frac{y}{2}=\tan^{-1}x+c$

$tan^{-1}\frac{y}{2}=2(\tan^{-1}x+c)$

$\frac{y}{2}=tan(2(tan^{-1}x+c))$

$y=2\tan(2(\tan^{-1}x+c))$

$$y(x) = 2 tan(2(\tan^{-1}x+c)) -- (||)$$

$y(1) = 2 \tan(2(tan^{-1}1+c))=2$

$2 tan(2(\tan^{-1}1+c))=2$

$tan(2(\tan^{-1}1+c))=1$

$tan(2(\tan^{-1}1+c))=tan(\frac{\pi}{4})$

$2(tan^{-1}1+c))=\frac{\pi}{4}$

$tan^{-1}1+c=\frac{\pi}{8}$

$\frac{\pi}{4}+c=\frac{\pi}{8}$

$c=\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{\pi}{4}$

$c=-\frac{\pi}{8} -- (|||)$

From, (||) and (|||) we have,

$y(x) = 2 \tan(2(tan^{-1}x-\frac{\pi}{8}))$

Comment: I need the value of $y(2)$.

Comment: So, where is your result for $y(2)$, plus what is the question?

Comment: @RajeshKSingh: Your $y(x)$ is correct, so [$y(2)$ =](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+Tan%5B%282+%28%28ArcTan%5B2%5D%29+-+pi%2F8%29%29%5D)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac12\arctan \frac y2=\arctan x+c$$

As $y(1)=2, \frac12\arctan 1=\arctan 1+c$
$\implies c=-\frac12\arctan 1=-\frac\pi8$

So, $$\frac12\arctan\frac y2=\arctan x-\frac\pi8\iff \arctan y=2\arctan x-\frac\pi4$$

$$\implies \frac y2=\tan\left(2\arctan x-\frac\pi4\right)$$
$$=\frac{\tan(2\arctan x)-\tan\frac\pi4}{1+\tan(2\arctan x)\tan\frac\pi4}\text{ applying }\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$$

As $2\arctan x=\arctan \frac{2x}{1-x^2}, \tan(2\arctan x)=\tan\left(\arctan \frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$

$$\implies \frac y2=\frac{\frac{2x}{1-x^2}-1}{1+\frac{2x}{1-x^2}}=\frac{2x-1+x^2}{1-x^2+2x}$$

Comment: Did a factor (product of 2) get lost?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee : Thank you !!

Comment: @Amzoti, thanks for your observation. Rectified.

Comment: @RajeshKSingh, please find the rectified answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Upvote (+1) on your nice answer (and it matches the MMA in my linked comment)!